# Seeming incompatiblity between Asp.Net Menus and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser

When you click on an Asp.Net menu in Chrome, the submenu items are not displayed and the aspnet menu disappears.

Anyone have an easy way to get this to work?  Is it a z-order issue?

Comment: It would be rather surprising if this didn't work in general. Its more likely an issue with your particular implementation. Post the relevant code etc and see what feedback you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem of the asp.net menu disappearing when trying to click a submenu item in Chrome and Safari browsers:

Add the following code to Page_Load :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0 )
            {
                Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
            }
    }
```